# Why is my dog suddenly pooping many times in the house?

Tags: health

My dog is 1.5 years old, and so far his potty training has been complete for the past year. Suddenly for one day, he pooped 5 times inside the house. I doubt this is because of stress because he seems happy and playful, and he is used to being left alone for an hour a day. I also don't think it is because of his diet, because he has had the same food for 6 months without any problems. It would be great if you could think of anything wrong with my dog, and if you recommend going to the vet.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

He might have something like a stomach flu. Make sure to give him many opportunities to go outside to use the toilet for a few days and observe how many times he poops.

If he doesn't go back to normal in 3 - 5 days, scoop some fresh poop into an empty and clean container (like an empty food jar) and go to a vet with the jar and your dog. The vet might check the poop for parasites or bacteria.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it has been almost 2 days, and he might be a little better